# How to create or use a portable java installation

Tags: java, jdk

So this is pretty simple, I am running a set of tools on windows, however to avoid issues regarding a lack of java installation I have bundled with my installation its own jre folder which in windows allows me to simply run a java virtual machine with a .bat and run my program.

My question, am I able to do the same on linux without java, I know my program works fine on ubuntu so far as long as it has java installed, but I am now running into issues regarding certain linux computers that do not have java installed at all. How would I call the java folder inside my program to run a virtual machine to run the .jar?    Would it be the same process? I already have a .sh that opens java and runs my virtual machine , it starts with a java command followed by -jar.  example: java -jar -xmx1024m ./myprogram.jar .

How would I change that command above to use a java or portable java installation inside my program folder? how can I create a portable java in linux also as I am pretty sure that the jre folder I have which works on windows will not work on java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to download a portable copy of the JDK for Linux. OpenJDK may be a better option, but since some programs refuse to run with it,
here I'll demonstrate using the Oracle JDK. **DISCLAIMER:** if you're going to be redistributing this then you need to be careful that you're not violating Oracle's EULA.

So with that out of the way, head over to [JDK download site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html), accept the license agreement, and then select the `.tar.gz` Linux option:

[image]

Save it in a clean directory of your choice. After the download has completed, open a terminal window and `cd` into that directory you just created.

Now we need to extract the archive:

```
tar -xzf jdk*.tar.gz
rm jdk*.tar.gz
```

You now have a portable JDK. Next, copy your JAR file into the directory as well.

Now we just need to create a script to launch it. Let's use `nano`:

```
nano launchApplication.sh
```

And paste in this text (replace `helloWorld.jar` with your JAR filename):

```
#!/bin/bash

jdk*/bin/java -jar helloWorld.jar
```

Now press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file. Now exit `nano` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Now that we've created the script, we need to make it executable by running the following command:

```
chmod +x launchApplication.sh
```

Finally, you can run your program with the portable JDK by doing:

```
./launchApplication.sh
```